# Update logged user password laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i want to add password update option for logged user therefore i used following code

controller  auth\authController.php

```
public function updatePassword()
    {

        $user = Auth::user();
        $rules = array(
            'old_password' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|alphaNum|between:6,16|confirmed'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::route('change-password', $user->id)->withErrors($validator);
        } else {
            if (!Hash::check(Input::get('old_password'), $user->password)) {
                return Redirect::route('change-password', $user->id)->withErrors('Your old password does not match');
            } else {
                $user->password = Input::get('password');
                $user->save();
                return Redirect::route('change-password', $user->id)->with("message", "Password have been changed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Routes

```
Route::post('change-password', 'Auth\AuthController@updatePassword');
Route::get('change-password', 'Auth\AuthController@updatePassword');
```

im getting following error

```
FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 123:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found
```

for this line "$user = Auth::user();"

Answer (score 1):

Your question has hidden answer..I have similar problem like @faz..I have done the trick with his question's code actually

**The correct way to achieve this -**

```
 protected function postChangePassword(ChangePasswordFormRequest $request){

    $user = Auth::user();
    $current_password = Input::get('current_password');
    $password = bcrypt(Input::get('password'));

    $user_count = DB::table('users')->where('id','=',$this->user_id)->count();

    if (Hash::check($current_password, $user->password) && $user_count == 1) {
        $user->password = $password;
        try {
            $user->save();
            $flag = TRUE;
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            $flag = FALSE;
        }
        if($flag){
            return redirect('/u/0/change/password')->with('success',"Password changed successfully.");
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/u/0/change/password')->with("danger","Unable to process request this time. Try again later");
        }
    }
    else{
        return redirect('/u/0/change/password')->with("warning","Your current password do not match our record");
    }
}
```

Please note for Hash and Auth, we need to include class at the top and user_id I have get through constructor `$this->user_id = Auth::user()->id;`. I think I have helped people.

Answer (score 0):

Its namespace issue, Try :

```
//if this method is not protected by a middleware for only authenticated users
//verify that user is currently logged in:

if(!$user = \Auth::user()) abort(503); //or return redirect()->route('login')

$rules = array(
    'old_password' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required|alphaNum|between:6,16|confirmed'
);
```

Or Add the namespace at the top of your `AuthController`

```
use Auth;

class AuthController{
   ....
}
```

Comment: ok its fixed . thanks now im getting ErrorException in AuthController.php line 138: Trying to get property of non-object error for $user->id and $user->password

Comment: you can add this: `if(!$user = Auth::user()) abort(404);` //or redirect user to login page or You can also use a middleware.

Comment: if you have guest middleware in your authcontroller construct method, then you need to exempt `updatePassword` from guest middleware, example: `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['updatePassword']]);`

Comment: @Digitlimit now im getting redirectloop error , but id is passing through url :(

Comment: may I see your AuthController code? especially your __construct()

Answer (score 0):

You didn't import Auth class.

add this at the top of the file. after the namespace.

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Comment: You can simply import `Auth` because of Laravel's aliases. Although, an import isn't strictly necessary; you can call `\Auth` directly.

Comment: @dakine ok its fixed . thanks now im getting ErrorException in AuthController.php line 138:
Trying to get property of non-object error for $user->id and $user->password

Comment: this  ErrorException  means that `$user` is not an object, which means that user is not currently logged in

Comment: @Digitlimit : ok any idea why its always reidrect to home page after login . even though i try to access change-password page

Comment: home is set in your redirectPath()

Comment: public function redirectPath()
 {
  if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath'))
  {
   return $this->redirectPath;
  }

  return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
 }

Comment: @dakine yes i have that code in my authController , is that the issue ?

Comment: do you have any middleware in your authcontroller?

Comment: that's where you get redirected when you login. you can change it if you want to get redirected to a different page.

Comment: @Digitlimit yes  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
  if ($this->auth->check())
  {
   return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));
  }

  return $next($request);
 }

Comment: its on RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

Comment: sorry I mean you should exempt it from guest middleware, example: `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['updatePassword']]);`

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand your issue you just use auth namespace of laravel, just write this line at top of your controller file

```
use Auth;
```

will solve your problem.